# Ensure you stay in bound of an array with an offset

Tags: javascript, arrays

I don't know why but I can't wrap my head around this right now.

I have an array with a size of 6 elements.

When I iterate through the array I calculate the new index based on the current index + offset, when the index exceeds the size of the array it should start at back at 0.

```
offset = 0:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6

offset = 1;
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1

...
```

Comment: I know the solution isn't difficult I've done it before, I lost it though. I somehow can't come up with anything right now

Comment: `%` is your best friend

Comment: ^^^ that is, `nextIndex = (currIndex + offset) % array.length`

Answer (score 0):

Here is some pseudo code that I think may answer your question. Note that this simply prints the array items based on the offset. I assume this is what you're looking for based on your example

```
current position = 0
offset = x
index  = current position + offset
array  = [ 1, 2, ..., 6 ]
length = number of items in array
i = 0

while i < length
  if index < length
    print array[index]
    index = index + 1
    i = i + 1
  else
    index = 0
```

Basically we will print each item at `array[index]` until we reach the end. At this point `index` is set to 0, the beginning of the array. `i` serves as the iterator that will ensure we only look at each item once.